# spark Exception in task xx in stage xx (TID xx): Java heap space

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, out-of-memory, shuffle

hi I run into below issue when running spark on yarn

```
22/11/11 04:46:35 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 119 remote fetches in 75 ms
22/11/11 04:46:35 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 530 (3.5 GiB) non-empty blocks including 0 (0.0 B) local and 0 (0.0 B) host-local and 530 (3.5 GiB) remote blocks
22/11/11 04:46:35 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 4 remote fetches in 5 ms
22/11/11 04:48:32 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
22/11/11 04:48:32 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 160.1 in stage 2.0 (TID 1260): Java heap space
22/11/11 04:48:32 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
```

Here are some of my spark configs :

```
--driver-memory 16g --executor-memory 16g --conf spark.executor.memory=6144
```

and code that above error happen, last line is where error throws

```
val sampleWindow = Window.partitionBy("productId").orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand())
val dfSampled = dfJoined.withColumn("row_number", row_number.over(sampleWindow)).filter(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("row_number") <= 10000).drop("row_number")

val convertedItemRecordDF = dfSampled.toDF.as[ItemRecord]    
convertedItemRecordDF.groupByKey(_.productId).agg(ItemLCSPerProductAggregator.toColumn.name("LCS")).write.option("header", true).option("compression", "gzip").csv(finalOutPut.toString
```

)

I'm new to spark, the node that has above error task config are as below show

Memory Used=8G | Memory Total=66GB | VCores Used=2 | VCores Avail=23

Answer (score 0):

seems like the groupByKey operation caused OOM in executor,try to give more memory to executor.
BTW,the driver doesn't need 16G memory at all,4G is enough.

Comment: thx, let me try this